# SVN: How to create a private svn folder online

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How to create a private svn folder online so that I can work on my project and update it online while I am traveling. I don't know if this is good place to ask related to this. Let me know if I am at wrong place.

Operating System: Windows 7 X64 or Windows 8 x64

Comment: What operating system are you using? The options available might depend on this.

Comment: I have updated my description with OS detail. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Do you trust to online provate svn hosting? Do you need the branching of repo files?

Comment: @Y.N Do you think it is safe? If no do you have any other option?

Comment: It depend on how important your files is. If doubt, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34793164/3578861

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If working in windows, one combination that you could try is

1. Creating a dropbox account and setting it up in your computer, so your files sync automatically.
2. Installing boxcriptor (http://boxcriptor.com), this will let you create encrypted folders in your operating system. The beauty of this is that you can encrypt folders in your cloud storage mounted folder. In this way you can keep your repository secure (I guess that's what you mean with private).
3. If you don't have TortoiseSVN, install it (https://tortoisesvn.net/)
4. Using BoxCriptor, create an encrypted folder within your dropbox, for instance, you can call it "MyEncryptedRepo". Make sure that you do this in the special drive created by boxcriptor. At this point you will be asked if you want the folder contents to be encrypted.
5. Navigate into you encrypted folder "MyEncryptedRepo" from the special drive letter offered by boxcryptor using the file explorer.
6. There, right click in any place to bring the context menu. Open the TortoiseSVN sub-menu, and click "Create Repository here". This repository will be encrypted.
7. To verify that encryption works and files are only readable in your computer, you can open your web-interface to dropbox, all files will be post-pended with an extension .bc, which is the encrypted version of the SVN original files. If you try to open any of these files with .bc extension, they will be "garbled" due to encryption.
8. You can still use this online repository by connecting to it as if it was a local repository from your computer if you access if from the drive letter mounted by boxcryptor.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you have the DropBox to sync, why use the svn on second level?

Comment: Dropbox won't offer the advantages of a repository, like version tracking, branching, tragging, etc. Therefore, if the goal is version control or software development, Dropbox on its own might lack capabilities as opposed to a repository. I used SVN in the example because the question is how to have a private online repository accessible anywhere.

Comment: Using Dropbox to house your repository can be dangerous. If you have 2 offline computers that you work on, when you reconnect and Dropbox re-syncs, you will have conflicted files in the repository database and if it's even possible to recover from that, you will almost certainly lose work. You'll have an even bigger problem if you use an encrypted drive image inside the Dropbox folder.

Answer (score 3):

Some options added to @Jorge Torres [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34779463/3578861):

- Use the online private svn hosting like Assembla or RiouxSVN
- Run your own svn-server on home PC and link to it through ssh tunnel
- Run your svn-server on VPS